# SD card related random freezes

Tags: sd-card, crash

I am using raspberry pi 2 (B+) in a biology lab to do real time tracking of small insects.
Basically, we have an `python`/`opencv` program that detect positions of animals and saves it in a `MySQL` db.
We typically run experiments for 2 weeks on sometimes as many as 30 pis simultaneously.
Often, some of our pis will freeze: the green ACT LED does not blink any more and they do not respond to ping/ssh. The power LED remains on, and the only way I find to reboot the devices is to power them off by hand.
This is very hard to reproduce in so far as a device can run fine for several days and then crash (or not).
`journalctl` does not provide any clues after it happens.

We keep a log of crashing devices, and it appears that some have never crashed while others keep crashing after a few days.

For several reasons, we think it is related to faulty SD cards:

- We had a much higher propensity to crash with alternative cards (Verbatim microSDHC, 32GB class 10).
- Swapping cards between devices indicates that the issue is related to the card -- as opposed to the not the power supply or other hardware issue.
- It does not seem that we run out of RAM either

I have tried to:

- Reburn card from img file
- Update firmware
- Use Pi3

Because of the random nature of the bug, testing every possible solution is a matter of time and statistics, so I am not quite sure where to start.

Technical details:

`$ uname -a
Linux e043 4.4.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP Wed Jun 8 19:31:47 MDT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`

The SD cards we use are '32G Samsung EVO SD card':

`$ grep . /sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:*/* 2>/dev/null
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/cid:1b534d303030303010c337142500f147
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/csd:400e00325b590000ee7f7f800a404055
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/date:01/2015
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/erase_size:512
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/fwrev:0x0
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/hwrev:0x1
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/manfid:0x00001b
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/name:00000
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/oemid:0x534d
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/preferred_erase_size:4194304
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/scr:02b5800200000000
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/serial:0xc3371425
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/type:SD
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/uevent:DRIVER=mmcblk
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/uevent:MMC_TYPE=SD
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/uevent:MMC_NAME=00000
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/uevent:MODALIAS=mmc:block`

Boot config file (Pi3)

`$ /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd get_config int
arm_freq=1200
audio_pwm_mode=1
config_hdmi_boost=5
core_freq=400
desired_osc_freq=0x36ee80
disable_camera_led=1
disable_commandline_tags=2
disable_l2cache=1
force_eeprom_read=1
force_pwm_open=1
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
framebuffer_swap=1
gpu_freq=300
hdmi_force_cec_address=65535
init_uart_clock=0x2dc6c00
lcd_framerate=60
over_voltage_avs=0x13d62
overscan_bottom=48
overscan_left=48
overscan_right=48
overscan_top=48
pause_burst_frames=1
program_serial_random=1
sdram_freq=450
temp_limit=85`

Comment: *"journalctl does not show anything at all **before it happens**"* is a little like saying "My car was fine before it drove off the cliff".  That's a little snarky and of course for some problems -- particularly I/O failure, which is what you've said seems a likely candidate -- it might.  However: Have you tried examining `/var/log/syslog` for clues after rebooting?  Have you tried plugging in a screen and keyboard before rebooting to see if it is possible to do some diagnostics that way?

Comment: SD Card manufacturers do not support using them for an OS so this is not entirely unexpected. You could consider retiring cards which do not perform and/or try different brands. NOTE that there is no advantage in using Class10 cards on a Pi - even though they are better at HD video (they are optimised for high speed sequential writing). More practically you should try implementing the watchdog timer (included on the SOC) to detect failure and perform a graceful restart - this is the normal engineering approach because ANY system can fail for inexplicable reasons.

Comment: @goldilocks There is no `/var/log/syslog` in my system. My understanding is that it is centralised to systemd. I meant I looked at the system log, using journalctl after crash, to investigate what happened before.

Comment: @Milliways. Thanks, I think this is a good idea, and I am working on persistence of my software after reboot, I will investigate how to make a watchdog.

Comment: Normative syslog implementations, including `rsyslog`, are interoperable with journald, and on stock Raspbian this is enabled by default and configured such that a copy of all messages should be present in `/var/log/syslog` -- so either you've disabled this, which is probably pointless and unwise, or you are not running stock Raspbian (in which case indicating what OS you are using is not super relevant, but at least worth mentioning).  The advantage to this is that `/var/log/syslog` is a normal text file which is easy to examine if you remove the card after a crash (although not necessary).

Comment: I'll strongly disagree with Milliways WRT "there is no advantage in using Class 10 cards"  in that while the top speed of the Pi's SD card interface is slower than the top speed of a class 10 card, pretty much all of the cards reported as achieving the maximum *write* speed (20-25 MB/s) on the Pi are class 10 or better.  I'll concur with him about the usefulness of a watchdog timer here though.

Comment: Also: The conclusion that it is SD card failure seems like one that is simply convenient rather than one that much effort has been made to verify -- convenient in the sense that you don't have to make any further effort to diagnose the problem if you are satisfied with, "Well, the ACT light isn't blinking, I guess it is SD card failure...".  Using a watchdog timer will throw better light on whether or not the entire system is really failing, or whether it has simply stopped doing what you want and gone offline.

Comment: Having a MySQL db (or other db) on a SD card is risk. As an alternative, send the data over network to a remote db.

Answer (score 1):

Faced this problem in Jun 2020.
Just turn swap file off:

```
sudo dphys-swapfile swapoff
sudo dphys-swapfile uninstall
sudo update-rc.d dphys-swapfile remove
```

In `/etc/dphys-swapfile` set `CONF_SWAPSIZE=0` (was 100 fro me)

This fixed random freezing in my case.
Check result by `free` before, after and after reboot. `Swap` should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced problems with corrupting SD cards on the Pi 3, so I suspect this is what you are experiencing also. My solution was to use a different SD card. Another solution is to copy the ext4 filesystem to a USB memory stick and change the config on the boot partition of the SD card so that it points to the new location of the root filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

SD cards are flimsy little things. I had a similar issue with a fleet of BeagleBone Black. Since you've tracked down the issue to the SD card itself, and reflashing the card didn't solve your issue, replace the SD card. They are cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I always try to stick with class 4 (or lower) microSD cards, and have never had this problem. Do you supply enough current? Do you have some USB gadget that pulls >100mA? Insufficient power is a nasty microSD cause-of-death. My Pi2B+ gets 2A.

I am not putting much faith in the 'use highest quality samsung/knownbrand SDHC' lore. All my cards are noname and cheap. I leave a bit (15-20%) unallocated, since I expect they will degrade faster. Just rename the resize script to autoresizeforfuturereference.sh and move it to /root before booting a freshly imaged microSD card to prevent the autoresize.

If your application requires heavy disk I/O, use a USB harddisk with a USB Y-cable, and power it from a sufficient source.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the following will do any good, but it won't hurt to give them a try.

1. I usually use this [F3](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3) (an alternative to h2testw utility) to perform a robust R/W tests on my microSD cards and/or USB memory sticks before I will use them.
2. As a double check, I also do some full checksums on a microSD card once I performed a *dd* to write an image OS on it.